# How to create separate log files for Scrapy spiders when running as a script

Tags: scrapy

I'm running Scrapy from script. From the documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script, I know I can get the project settings using get_project_settings(). So my code is as this.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.crawl(Spider2)
process.start()
```

But now I want to create individual log files for Spider1 and Spider2. I've tried setting the log configurations directly in the Spider1 and Spider2 classes. However when running the script Scrapy create two log files but everything gets written to first log file created.

```
class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
     custom_settings = {
    'LOG_FILE': 'spider1.log',
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
    'LOG_STDOUT': True
    }
class Spider2(scrapy.Spider):
     custom_settings = {
    'LOG_FILE': 'spider2.log',
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
    'LOG_STDOUT': True
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this scenario.

Comment: I wouldn’t discard this being a bug.